# synchronous loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

```js
//Importing: postges DB connection
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://readxxx:p@ssword@vmwoxxx-tst:8888/worxxx";
var prvsiteid = '';
var cursiteid = '';
var qurystring = '';

pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
    return;
  }
  
  client.query("select site_id,created_at,started_at,completed_at,notes,finish_code from _background_tasks where finish_code > 0 and site_id > 0 and abs(extract(Epoch from (now()::timestamp without time zone - completed_at)))/60 <= 4600 order by site_id asc", function(err, result1) {
    done();
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error running query', err);
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < result1.rowCount; i++) {
      cursiteid = result1.rows[i].site_id;
      if (prvsiteid != cursiteid) {
        prvsiteid = cursiteid;
        qurystring = "select trim(su.name) as name, case When trim(su.email) is null then su.name || '@netapp.com' when trim(su.email) > '' then su.name || '@netapp.com' else su.name end uemail,su.friendly_name as frdname from system_users su where su.state = 'active' and su.id in (select distinct(system_user_id) from users u where u.site_id = " + cursiteid + "and u.admin_level >= 5)"
        client.query(qurystring, function(err, result2) {
          done();
          if (err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
            return;
          }
          for (var j = 0; j < result2.rowCount; j++) {
            console.log(cursiteid, result2.rows[j].name, result2.rows[j].uemail, result2.rows[j].frdname);
          }
        });
      }
      console.log(result1.rows[i].site_id, result1.rows[i].created_at, result1.rows[i].started_at, result1.rows[i].completed_at);
    }
  });
});
```

I know NodeJS programs are asynchronous but this scenario I intend it to be synchronous.

for loop(outer) --> for loop(inner) when outer forloop changes with new site id i want to send email to all the emailids from inner loop and also the resultant rows of the each site of outer loop has to printed.

Comment: Please format your code nicely.

Comment: You need to use something like [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each). Also I believe calling `done` right after your first `client.query` is wrong

Comment: i am a days baby to nodejs even to java family... please help me understand what changes i need to make in my code to result as expecting... Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

1. If the library you are using doesn't support synchronous operations, you can't use it synchronously without abominations (You do **not** want abominations in your code. No matter how much the boss is pressing).
2. You can fairly simply perform loops and other actions on asynchronous operations by using **[Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)**, specifically, **[bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)** which supports the ability to take callback-based asynchronous functions and transform them into Promise-ready functions.

Comment: i am a days baby to nodejs even to java family... please help me understand what changes i need to make in my code to result as expecting... Appreciate your help